# Resolution settings not saved

Tags: resolution

I'm new to Linux, and I just installed elementaryOS. The first thing I do is change the resolution to 1680 x 1050 so that I can see things properly, but when I reboot, the resolution is set back to 2256 x 1338. How can I change it permanently so that it doesn't change? I've heard of using a tool called `xrandr` but I'm still new to Linux and can't figure out how to use it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo vi /usr/sbin/lightdm-session
```

Here is how the first part of that file looks now:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# LightDM wrapper to run around X sessions.

echo "Running X session wrapper"

# Load profile
for file in "/etc/profile" "$HOME/.profile" "/etc/xprofile" "$HOME/.xprofile"; do
  if [ -f  "$file" ]; then
     echo "Loading profile from $file";
     . "$file"
  fi
done

-- Here add the xrandr settings

# Load resources
```

Press INS (insert) button or i on your keyboard. This will go into the insert mode and you can use go to the end of the line , press enter and put the content I described below.

Copy below:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00" 85.25 1680 1368 1440 1576 1784 1050 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode CRT1 1680x1050_60.00
xrandr --output CRT1 --mode 1680x1050_60.00
```

Paste into the file with the right button of the mouse, where I marked it with this section:

```
-- Here add the xrandr settings
```

Press Esc button on your keyboard. Then type :x to save and exit. Restart the Elementary OS. Check does it work.

Comment: I did what you explained, but when I copy pasted, I replaced "CRT1" with the name of my display, but when I reboot, the display resolution is still 2256 x 1338.

Comment: Try to replace CRT1 with LCD1 and then check.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything. I tried checking the file for errors, then switching from CRT1 to LCD1 and back. But the resolution always resets when I restart.